# Manually specify location of .vagrant folder in Vagrantfile

Tags: build, vagrant

The folder where I have Vagrantfile is being auto-generated during the build, so it gets cleaned up, but I'd like to still be able to use the created machines. The easiest way would be to put .vagrant folder somewhere outside the auto-generated folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

1. Use `VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH` to set the the location where the project specific data is stored (defaults to `.vagrant` as you already know). Note that the path has to be project/Vagrantfile specific.
2. `cd` to a directory where you want the `.vagrant` directory to be created, and use `VAGRANT_VAGRANTFILE` to specify the path to the generated Vagrantfile.

Comment: According to [Vagrant's documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html) VAGRANT_VAGRANTFILE "is not a file path, but just a filename.".

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to specify the metadata directory without mucking about with environment variables each time. Just put this in the top of your Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH = 'custom/dotfile/path'
if(ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'].nil? && '.vagrant' != VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH)
    puts 'changing metadata directory to ' + VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH
    ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'] = VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH
    puts 'removing default metadata directory ' + FileUtils.rm_r('.vagrant').join("\n")
    system 'vagrant ' + ARGV.join(' ')
    ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'] = nil #for good measure
    abort 'Finished'
end
```

Comment: Since my dev directory lives on nfs, the .vagrant directory gets messed up when more than one host tries to run it's vm. This seems to fix it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It prints "warning: already initialized constant VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH" four times and then exits immediately at the `abort` line.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted each provider to use a separate Vagrant directory to easily be able to swap between them. I could not get [@hairraisin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25904132/96588) to work, but based on that I ended up with the following:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.provider :lxd do |lxd, override|
    if ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'].nil?
      ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'] = '.vagrant-lxd'
      puts 'Removing default metadata directory ' + FileUtils.rm_r('.vagrant').join("\n")
      exec 'vagrant ' + ARGV.map{|arg| Shellwords.escape arg}.join(' ')
    end
    …
```

This avoids endless recursion or `abort`ing too early. `exec` rather than `system` avoids a non-zero exit code from every `vagrant` command.